# Unable to install tensorflow in R-studio

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I have been unable to get `tensorflow` to work in my R-studio. Every time I try to use `install_tensorflow()` R-studio throws the below error

> Error in conda_python(envpath, conda = miniconda) :
> no conda environment exists at path 'C:/Users/yaswanth/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate'

Below are the steps I followed

-I have created an environment TensorFlowEnvironment in my anaconda.
-I have installed Tensorflow in this environment
-Launched R studio from this environment
-I ran the following two lines of code

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
```

-But when I third line of code

```
install_tensorflow()
```

I get the error that no condo environment named as r-reticulate exist. Should I create a new environment named as r-reticulate? I am a `tensorflow` beginner so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OP, check the documentation for Tensorflow.  It states [in the installation quick start](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/) that you need Anaconda installed if you're running Windows.  For other systems, you can check the documentation for further help.  Based on the error message you're getting, there's something either wrong with your setup for the condo / Anaconda or that you need to install that first.  The path given in your error has me to understand you are installing on Windows, so check Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In Anaconda Navigator, in the Environments pane, create a new environment (click on create+ button) and name it "rminiconda". Include both Python and R (checkboxes in the popup window. Then in RStudio, tools/Options/Python, choose the new environment for Python.